# install dlib 19.16.0 in python 3.7.1

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, dlib

i have this problem during install dlib 19.16.0 in python3.7.1 
 the conda version i use is (conda 4.5.12)

```
(base) C:\Users\TAQA>conda install dlib=19.16.0
```

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> ```
>  - dlib=19.16.0
> ```
>
> Current channels:
>
> ```
>  - https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/win-64
>  - https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/noarch
>  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
>  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
>  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> ```
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
>      looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
>    https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

please help me

Comment: At anaconda.org you can search for the package in other channels. If you've found the right one, the site will give you the install instructions (e.g. `conda install -c derickl dlib`). But with a quick look, I haven't been able to find version 19.16 yet, except for OSX.

Comment: If you don't really need to install extractly dlib 19.16.0, installing by wheel file could be much easier https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/.